# Finding the covariance matrix of $Y=AX$ where $X$ is a known multivariate gaussian random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, covariance, multivariate-statistical-analysis

> For $X=(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ with Gaussian distribution, covariance matrix $2I_3$ ($2$ multiplied by the identity matrix), and mean vector $\mu$ = $(3,3,3)^T$, I want to find the covariance matrix of $Y=(Y_1,Y_2,Y_3)^T$ where
>
> $$Y=\begin{pmatrix}1/\sqrt 2 & 0 & -1/\sqrt 2 \\1/\sqrt 3 & 1/\sqrt 3 & 1/\sqrt 3\\ 1/\sqrt 6 & -2/\sqrt 6 & 1/\sqrt 6\\
> \end{pmatrix}X$$

I know that when I use the definition of the covariance matrix in terms of expectations, my answer is $2I$ (which is the correct answer).

However when I substitute in $Y=AX=A(2Z+\mu)=2AZ+A\mu$, the covariance matrix of Y is $(2A)(2A)^T$ which simplifies to $4I_3$.

However, this contradicts the correct answer $2I_3$.

I hope someone could clarify this for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Careful, your substitution for $X$ (and thus your substitution for $Y$) is not correct. For $X$ to have covariance $2I$, then you must have $$Y = A \underbrace{(\sqrt{2} Z + \mu)}_{=^D X}$$
with the equality being in distribution.

After you retrace your steps, you'll get the desired covariance.

Comment: Thanks. Just realised I used Variance instead of standard deviation in my substitution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of the linear transformation,
$\mathbf{y=Ax}$,
the covariance of $\mathbf{y}$ is given by
$\mathbf{\Sigma}_y=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{\Sigma}_x\mathbf{A}^T$
which in your case simplifies into
$\mathbf{\Sigma}_y=2\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^T=2 \mathbf{I}_3$

Comment: Is there a generalisation to y=Ax+b?

Comment: the formula is identical in this case (the covariance is not affected by offset)